# sass multiple themes in angular

Tags: sass, themes, angular

Let's say I have two themes (light & dark) in an angular app > 2, and a toggle button which is already configured to add the theme class to the **body** tag

variables.scss

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    backgroundColor: #fff,
    textColor: #408bbd,
    borderColor: #254fe5,
  ),
  dark: (
    backgroundColor: #222,
    textColor: #ddd,
    borderColor: #2e4dd2,
  ),
);
```

I tried different approaches I found ([here](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1#.9n1bdu7h7) and [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/organizing-multiple-theme-styles-with-sass/)), but none worked.

I also tried the simplest approach

about.component.scss

```
.theme-dark .page-title{
  color: white;
}

.theme-light .page-title{
  color: red;
}
```

I know the class `.theme-dark` on body tag is not recognized from a component style, but I can't find any solution.

What approach can I use to get multiple themes in such modules system?

Comment: If you want to change the theme at runtime apply the root class with condition and the approach i use that is throw a variable using webpack and retrieve it in angular then apply sass files regarding theme name

Comment: @BabarBilal I apply the root class with condition, but I didn't get how to apply the sass files, I'm looking for a way to apply from the component style

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:host-context` in a scoped angular component.  Here is your example:

about.component.scss

```
:host-context(.theme-dark) .page-title{
  color: white;
}

:host-context(.theme-light) .page-title{
  color: red;
}
```

Then you need an instance e.g. a service that can change the CSS class at top level to switch the theme.

When you don't need to support IE11 or other legacy browser take a look at CSS Custom Properties (CSS Variables) to change the values at runtime. This reduces your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has provided us a feature called var(), which allows us to runtime change properties of our CSS elements.
For more details, you can check my blog on this [here](https://medium.com/@nijaunjal/multiple-css-themes-in-angular-277dfaadda03)