# Sass Angular + theming

Tags: angular, sass

I have a question on the use of sass and Angular 6. My goal is to have several template: a blue and an orange, so I would like to create 2 variables.scss files with variables in each file, but then via angular, I can not achieve this, taking into account that I would optimize to max the weight of the file css (I can not find a simple solution to implement).

thk

Comment: Does it have to be in 2 files ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I like, the idea of having 2 files with variables inside is all

Answer (score 4):

I Suggest you use one scss file with different properties.

Example

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    backgroundColor: #fff
  ),
  dark: (
    backgroundColor: #222
  ),
);
```

Then use the following in your app

```
<main id="app-root" [class]="theme">

</main>

let theme = 'theme-light'; // or theme-dark
```

References for the above
* [easy-color-theming-with-scs](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1)
* [organizing-multiple-theme-styles-with-sass](https://zellwk.com/blog/organizing-multiple-theme-styles-with-sass/)
* [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035538/sass-multiple-themes-in-angular)

Created a small [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:e5gDneScpWFRIwj48PEz?p=preview)

Comment: Thk Tinus, but today I am on a very big application and I had already seen the links but it involves a lot of code to manage all this (duplication of the file almost) and I look for a simple solution in the code. Have you ever had this problem?

Comment: I did not yet have this problem, though not sure why it would be a lot of supplication if the styling gets separated correctly.

Comment: Oui mais cela veut dire que pour la déclaration d'un bouton, tu vas dupliquer du code (pas tout mais une partie) et par rapport à cela, j'esperais qu'il y aurait une solution plus simple